# Grunt task doesn't continue on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, macos, gruntjs

Grunt task doesn't continue on Windows.

Hi! there.

I have question that how to use grunt on Windows.
I have been using compass,watch, and sftp-deploy by grunt task on Mac and Windows.

### Mac's result was below.

```
Completed in 8.849s at Tue Sep 09 2014 18:04:52 GMT+0900 (JST) - Waiting...
>> File "sass/hiratsuka29.scss" added.
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
write stylesheets/hiratsuka29.css (0.746s)

Running "sftp-deploy:build" (sftp-deploy) task
>> Logging in with key at /Users/shhirats/shhirats/shhirats_secure.key
>> Concurrency : 4
transferred=[3/46] elapsed=[0.2s] overall=[7%] eta=[2.3s] [=== ]>>
Directories done.
transferred=[4/46] elapsed=[0.4s] overall=[9%] eta=[3.8s] [=== ]>>
Transferred : 0.001953125 Mb

Done, without errors.
```

### Waiting...

Grunt task had been continueing on Mac.

### Windows result was below.

```
C:\gittmp7\ShiftCustomer\ShiftCustomer\ShiftCustomer\public\assets>grunt
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "scss\sm\part\work-list.scss" changed.
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
unchanged img/sm/sprites-s2c9a5e2425.png
unchanged img/sm/icon-sa7be2049da.png
   write css/sm/part/work-list.css (2.976s)

Running "sftp-deploy:build" (sftp-deploy) task
>> Logging in with key at C:\ssh\key\shinya.key
>> Concurrency : 4
  transferred=[1/16] elapsed=[0.0s] overall=[6%] eta=[0.0s] [=                ]
  transferred=[2/16] elapsed=[0.1s] overall=[13%] eta=[0.6s] [==              ]
  transferred=[3/16] elapsed=[0.2s] overall=[19%] eta=[0.7s] [===              ]
  transferred=[4/16] elapsed=[0.2s] overall=[25%] eta=[0.7s] [====            ]
  transferred=[5/16] elapsed=[0.3s] overall=[31%] eta=[0.7s] [=====            ]
  transferred=[6/16] elapsed=[0.4s] overall=[38%] eta=[0.7s] [======          ]
>> Directories done.
  transferred=[7/16] elapsed=[0.7s] overall=[44%] eta=[0.8s] [=======          ]
  transferred=[8/16] elapsed=[0.7s] overall=[50%] eta=[0.7s] [=========        ]
>> Transferred : 0.072265625 Mb
 Running "watch" task
 Completed in 6.506s at Tue Sep 09 2014 18:11:18 GMT+0900 (東京 (標準時)) - Waiti
 ng...
>> Transferred : 0.072265625 Mb
 Running "compass:dist" (compass) task

 Running "sftp-deploy:build" (sftp-deploy) task
>> Logging in with key at C:\ssh\key\shinya.key
>> Concurrency : 4
  transferred=[1/16] elapsed=[0.0s] overall=[6%] eta=[0.0s] [=                ]
  transferred=[2/16] elapsed=[0.1s] overall=[13%] eta=[0.5s] [==              ]
  transferred=[3/16] elapsed=[0.2s] overall=[19%] eta=[0.7s] [===              ]
  transferred=[4/16] elapsed=[0.2s] overall=[25%] eta=[0.7s] [====            ]
  transferred=[5/16] elapsed=[0.3s] overall=[31%] eta=[0.7s] [=====            ]
  transferred=[6/16] elapsed=[0.4s] overall=[38%] eta=[0.6s] [======          ]
>> Directories done.
>> Transferred : 0 Mb
 Done, without errors.
```

### C:\gittmp7\ShiftCustomer\ShiftCustomer\ShiftCustomer\public\assets>

Grunt task had moved twice,then Grunt task had finished on Windows.

Why does grunt task do twice on windows?
Why does grunt task finish on windows?

Please want to teach it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### I forgot Gruntfile.js

```
    module.exports = function(grunt){

  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),  //package.jsonを取得
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sftp-deploy');

  grunt.initConfig({      //grunt.initConfigの中にタスクの設定を記述する
    // options
    options: {
      livereload: true,
      nospawn: true
    },
    compass: {
      dist: {
        options: {                
          config: 'config.rb'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
　　options: {
        spawn: false
      },
      styles: {
        files: [
        'sass/*',
        'sass/sm/part/*'
        ],   //監視するファイルを指定（sassフォルダのscssファイル全て）
        tasks: ['compass','sftp-deploy']   //指定したファイルが変更された場合行うタスク（sassのコンパイルをする）
      }
    },
    // Live Reload
    connect: {
      livereload: {
        options: {
          port: 80
        }
      }
    },
    // gruntコマンド実行時にページをブラウザで開く
    open: {
      server: {
        path: 'http://indival.yahoo.co.jp:<%= connect.livereload.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    'sftp-deploy': {
      build: {
        auth: {
          host: 'dev.idv.portal.vallabo.info',
          port: 22,
          authKey: 'shhirats_user'
        },
        cache: 'sftpCache.json',
        src: 'stylesheets',
        dest: '/home/shhirats',
        serverSep: '/',
        concurrency: 4,
        progress: true
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch','compass','sftp-deploy']);
```

### };

I use it on Windows and Mac.